# How to Keep only latest file in the folder and move older files to Archive location

Tags: linux

In my folder I have multiple files similar to these:

```
ContractAdjustments.CHRS201804202144.txt
ContractAdjustments.CHRS201804212144.txt
ContractAdjustments.CHRS201804222144.txt
ContractAdjustments.CHRS201804232144.txt
```

I only want to keep the youngest file and move the rest to an archive location. I'm using the following script, which gives me an error:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname 'ContractAdjustments.*.TXT' -printf '%T@|%p\n' | sort -r -n | tail -n +2 | cut -d'|' -f2 | xargs -i mv {} ARCHV
```

Comment: Are the files in that directory always in that exact format and are they the only files in that directory?

Comment: What exactly does “latest “ mean to you?

Comment: it means every day i am receiving more than 1 file, i need to keep only one latest file and remaining need to archive before it process.

Comment: i am using this script i am getting error

Comment: $ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname 'ContractAdjustments.*.TXT' -printf '%T@|%p\n' | sort -r -n | tail -n +2 | cut -d'|' -f2 | xargs -i mv {} ARCHV

Comment: ^^ put that in your question please, where you can format it and we can _easily_ read it

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p ARCHIVE || exit 1

newest=
for file in ContractAdjustments.*.txt; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        if [ -z "$newest" ]; then
            # this is the first file, initialize "newest"
            newest=$file
        elif [ "$file" -nt "$newest" ]; then
            # file is newer than "newest",
            # archive "newest" and set new newest file
            mv -i "$newest" ARCHIVE
            newest="$file"
        else
            # file is older, archive it
            mv -i "$file" ARCHIVE
        fi
    fi
done

if [ -n "$newest" ]; then
    printf 'Done. Newest file = %s\n' "$newest"
else
    echo 'No files found'
fi
```

This script would, provided that `/bin/sh` implements the `-nt` test in its `[` built-in command, move all older files to an `ARCHIVE` folder, while keeping the newest file untouched.

It does this by iterating over the filenames matching the given pattern, and for each file, testing its timestamp against the newest file found so far, moving the files depending on whether they are newer or older.

The script properly takes care of preserving any space characters etc. in filenames. This may not be an issue in this particular case, but in general, a Unix filename may contain both spaces and embedded newlines, as well as filename globbing characters.

---

If you want to go by the way the *filename* sorts rather than by the timestamps on the files:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p ARCHIVE || exit 1

set -- ContractAdjustments.*.txt

while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
    mv -i "$1" ARCHIVE
    shift
done

printf 'Done. Newest file = %s\n' "$1"
```

This would set the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the list of files matching the given pattern.  Then, while there's still more than one file in the list, move the first file in the list to the `ARCHIVE` directory and shift it off the list.  The last file in the listis the one that sorts last according to its filename (this file is left in place).

Comment: @madhukarkorakandla No. Unless you mean that you want to wrap it in a script or in a shell function? The code is already written as a script.

Comment: i wrote like this but its deleting  only one old file, i need keep only one latest and reaming need to move to archive.#!/bin/bash
targetfile="$(ls /opt/informatica/server/infa_shared/MDM/SrcFiles/HealthTrust/ContractAdjustments.*.txt | sort -r | tail -n1)"
if [[ -f "$targetfile" ]]; then
    mv $targetfile /opt/informatica/server/infa_shared/MDM/SrcFiles/HealthTrust/Archive/
fi

Comment: @madhukarkorakandla That command has nothing to do with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be:

```
mv `ls -t ContractAdjustments.*.txt | awk '{ iteration+=1; if (iteration > 1) { print } } ' ` ARCHV
```

Of course, this will produce errors in edge conditions (e.g., if there's only one file in the directory), but it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Put a list of every file except the first in a variable and run a for loop on it.

```
 listinmemory=`ls -alht | tail -n +5 | awk '{print $9}'`; for each in $listinmemory; do mv $each /path/to/directory; done
```

`ls -alht` will list 4 lines that you don't want to run anything on,

```
total 123K
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user user 1.0K Jun 27 09:20 .
drwx------. 13 user user 2.0K Jun 27 10:36 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user 3.0K Jun  6 18:29 file1
```

the most recent file and 3 lines -- then all the files you do, so `tail -n +5` will skip the first 4 lines and run `mv $each /path/to/directory` on all the files it finds!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to parse `ls` so in your case, `cd` into the directory and go with this:

```
 for CA in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ContractAdjustments\*.txt | head --lines=-1); do mv $CA /path/to/archive/; done
```

Using a `for` loop with command substitution, that finds all of the files in the directory starting with the format of `ContractAdjustments*.txt` that you've specified and lists them in order of oldest to newest according to the date of the second octet. It is then piped into `--head --lines=-1` which prints all but the last line which is the newest file and passes the value to the `CA` variable (for ContractAdjustments). Finally, the `do` uses `mv` to move all except the newest file to the archive location.